# Using Twilio RestClient 5.x on a website's backend

Tags: c#, api, twilio

In the previous version (4.x), we were able to initilize a TwilioRestClient instance per request. In that way, we could generate clients to use for accounts and subaccounts.

Is it possible to do the same with the newest version (5.x)?

Comment: You need to read the documentation about the new version and try coding it.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Dev Evangelist here.

With the new version of the SDK for C#, there is no need to instantiate the RestClient more than once. You would initialize it by making a call to a static `TwilioClient.Init` method, passing in your account SID and auth token.

You can alternatively create your own REST client that derives from `ITwilioRestClient`, but that would totally depend on your use case.

Check out our migration docs [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp/migrating-your-csharp-dot-net-application-twilio-sdk-4x-5x). It provides details on this and other changes for migration scenarios.

Comment: So there is no way to execute calls with a subaccount instead of an account, right?

Comment: You can do that. What you want to do is set the AccountSID and AuthToken to the subaccount's SID and token. The static `TwilioClient` has methods to update that.

So those calls would look like `TwilioClient.SetAccountSid("SubAccountSID_HERE")` and `TwilioClient.SetPassword("SubAccountPassword_HERE")`. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: [UPDATE] So I want to correct my previous comment. Instead of calling those two methods to reset the account SID, make these calls: `TwilioClient.Invalidate()` (which will reset your client) and `TwilioClient.Init("SUBACCOUNT_SID","SUBACCOUNT_AUTHTOKEN")`. After setting the credentials this way, you can make calls from any phone number that the subaccount has access to. 

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: But with this approach, all the requests in the website will have the same accountid because TwilioClient and XXXResource will be singleton, right?

Comment: That is right. The TwilioClient is a singleton in the latest version of the SDK. It sounds like you have some specific ideas in mind. Mind shooting me a mail at corey@twilio.com to discuss further?

Comment: @CoreyWeathers  What about multithreading issues? what if i set credentials in thread A , then thread B set credentials, then thread A send the SMS. Thread A will be using Thread B credentials, which is wrong.

Comment: Just saw this and I'm super late here. I did a quick check of the source code on github and didn't see any explicit multi-threading support. I can follow up with the team that generates the helper library to see if this is in the works. 

Ideally though, if multithreading is a concern, of course there is the use of the double lock check before changing the creds on the client object.